# How to include arrayA to arrayB

Tags: php

How can i include this an arrayA

```
$info =array($lat3,$lon3);
```

to arrayB

```
$the_array[]= array{(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),...};
```

Comment: `array_merge` or `array_combine`. But can you please clear your question with some input and values and expected outcome based on those values?

Answer (score 2):

Use [***`array_merge`***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge

```
$array1 = array($lat3,$lon3);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: how can i make this $x = 0 ; and $y= {(array[0]),(array[1]),(array[2]),..(array[nth])};